# Quantum instant networking

Tags: networking

Anyone know of when quantum networking will be used to reduce internet ping? All we need is a transmitter in the middle of A and B and two sets of pulses. A and B just collapse or don't collapse the wave function to send the signal. I know it sounds tough but we have known about the quantum world for more than 90 years. There must be something on the way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, people have been talking about sending information using quantum theory for decades now.

Outside of some proposals to do [quantum cryptography](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Quantum_Cryptography) (which doesn't reduce internet ping times), there is no plan to use quantum networking.

Although one popular way of explaining quantum entanglement and collapse involves *something* traveling faster than the speed of light, unfortunately there appears to be no way to actually harness that *something* -- information transferred using quantum or any other means is, as far as we know, limited to the speed of light.

Since we're already sending normal pulses of light through optical fiber at pretty close(*) to the speed of light, the potential speedup seems limited.

- "[Does quantum entanglement imply faster than light communication?](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/137-physics/general-physics/particles-and-quantum-physics/810-does-quantum-entanglement-imply-faster-than-light-communication-intermediate)" No.
- "[The Real Reasons Quantum Entanglement Doesn't Allow Faster-Than-Light Communication](http://www.forbes.com/sites/chadorzel/2016/05/04/the-real-reasons-quantum-entanglement-doesnt-allow-faster-than-light-communication/#263291574810)"
- "[the no-communication theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/no-communication_theorem)"
- "[Quantum entanglement as practical method of superluminal communication](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78118/quantum-entanglement-as-practical-method-of-superluminal-communication)"
- etc.

(*) Light pulses travel through normal optical fibers at roughly 200 megameters/s, or about 2/3 "the" speed of light -- the speed of light in a vacuum.